# Two lined button with different font sizes?

Tags: html, button

`Hi, I'd like to make a button with two lines of text and have them in different font sizes... Is there any way? My current way was trying it with an kind of  designed button. Could that work in some way? Any help is appreciated! Beneath you see what I'm working with right now... I want to have a second line under "START" which is displayed in a much smaller font size

```
<a class="smallbtn">START</a>

.smallbtn {
font-family: "Lato Light";
background-color: #58B947;
border-radius:5px;
color: white;
padding: 15px 6px;
text-align: center;
text-decoration: none;
display: inline-block;
font-size: 21px;
width: 73%;
cursor: default;
margin-bottom: 5px;
```

}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you could do this if you just want to add a new line of text under your "START"

```
<a class="smallbtn">START<br><sub>hello</sub></a>
```

or

```
p{
font-size:12px;
padding:0px;margin:0px;}

<a class="smallbtn">START<br><p>hello</p></a>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try insert a div inside the button, give an id to the element and add css, like this:

```
<a class="smallbtn">START<div id="smallbtnFont">hello</div></a>

#smalbtnFont{
  font-family: "arial";
  font-size: 1em;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

good question, heres how:

```css
button {
font-family: "Lato Light";
background-color: #58B947;
border-radius:5px;
color: white;
padding: 15px 6px;
text-align: center;
text-decoration: none;
display: inline-block;
font-size: 21px;
width: 73%;
cursor: default;
margin-bottom: 5px;
}
```

```html
<button>Start<br><small style="font-size:50%;">Now</small></button>
```